# join table and has_many relationships not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations, has-many-through

I have two items, users and posts, and a join table linking them together.  The two items have a has_many relationship with each other (:through the join table).  I created the join table after creating the two databases.  The problem I am having is that I get errors every time I try and do something with @user.posts or @post.users.  It is almost like they are not set up correctly.  Somewhere I was reading that if you create an association after creating the model, then you have to use the add_column method.  Is that my problem?  I wasnt sure on how to implement that method or anything.  This is the error I get:

SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: users.post_id: SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."post_id" = 60 AND "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1

Looks like from the error I need to add a column but im not sure on how to do that.

here is my latest schema.db:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(:version => 20110930155455) do

  create_table "posts", :force => true do |t|
    t.text     "content"
    t.integer  "vote_count"
    t.text     "author"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.integer  "user_id"
  end

  create_table "users", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "user_name"
    t.string   "password"
    t.date     "time"
    t.integer  "posts_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.integer  "post_id"
  end

  create_table "votes", :force => true do |t|
    t.integer  "post_id"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

end
```

Comment: Could you post the parts of the current schema that has to do with the tables users, posts and the join table? You will find it in your application under `db/schema.rb`. And too the definition of the classes `User`, `Post` and the join model class (in case you have a concrete class for that). I second to use "has_many :through" associations however ...

Comment: +1 for posting model code and info about the join table.  Your users table should not have a post_id field and likewise, the posts table should not have a user_id field.  Those fields should be in the join table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you need to create a migration for the foreign keys.  You need to add `post_id` to the :users table with type integer.  Perform

```
rails g migration AddPostIdToUsers post_id:integer
```

to generate your migration.  You should create one that looks like

```
class AddPostIdToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :users, :post_id, :integer
  end
end
```

You might also want to consider setting up a *has_many :through association*, it'll give you more control.

Comment: I am using the :through association.  That did not seem to help.  I seem to be having problems with my table updating.  I realized I named a column in the posts table the same as my join table.  I tried to change the name and run rake db:migrate but nothing happens.  The name is not changed.  I dont know if I am creating these associations and stuff but nothing is actually getting updated?

Comment: In that case you need the FK's in your join table, not in User or Post.  You join table will essentially `belong_to :user` and `belong_to :post`.  Then perform `rake db:migrate` and you'll see these added in `schema.db`.  You can play around with the associations in the rails console and is a good way to check it's working.